# Http Authentication Client Library

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http, authentication, client

Is there any Java library to compute a Basic or Digest Http authentication?
Jersey-Client offers a way to do it, but without providing a way of using its computations out of its Http call.

For Basic Authentication, it's easy `Basic + base64(user:pass)` but Digest is slightly harder.

My problem happend on AppEngine where TaskQueue do not have any mechanism to compute an authentication header, but just a way to set it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like [this class](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/commons/httpclient/auth/DigestScheme.java.html) from Apache Commons HttpClient may have the capability to compute HTTP Digest headers independantly.